# How to write a simple content negotiation with apache

Tags: apache, content-negotiation, linked-data

I would like to write a rules that says, whenever that resource is requested, if the content type is X return the  file_x, if it is Y return file_Y

Can anyone help here ?

Many thanks,

-D-

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what's mentioned in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497550/linked-data-rdf-content-negotiation-with-apache), another alternative is to use a [type map file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html#negotiation). For example, I used the following file type map to serve my foaf profile.

```
URI: card

URI: card.ttl
Content-type: text/turtle; qs=1.0

URI: card.rdf
Content-type: application/rdf+xml; qs=0.8

URI: card.html
Content-type: text/html; qs=0.8

URI: card.trix
Content-type: application/trix; qs=0.8

URI: card.trig
Content-type: application/x-trig; qs=0.8

URI: card.n3
Content-type: text/rdf+n3; qs=0.8

URI: card.nt
Content-type: text/plain; qs=0.8
```

and here are the files.
http://people.apache.org/~nandana/id/